# Is there a way to find commons items in two columns of a data table in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame in the following format, where in column `dir_list_2` and `dir_list` contain a list of numbers in each cell. I want to create a new column `common_dir` which contains the common value in columns `dir_list_2` and `dir_list`.

For example if dir_list_2 is a list with (1,2,3,4) and dir_list is a list with (3,4,5) then common_dir should be a list with (3,4). I want to get this for each row.

```
data$common_dir <- intersect(data$dir_list_2,data$dir_list)
```

is not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intersect` in `Map` -

```
data$common_dir <- Map(intersect, data$dir_list, data$dir_list2)
data

#  a      dir_list dir_list2 common_dir
#1 1       2, 3, 4      3, 4       3, 4
#2 2       1, 2, 3      2, 3       2, 3
#3 3 1, 2, 3, 4, 5         9       NULL
```

which looks like this

[image]

Or using `rowwise` in `dplyr` which gives the same output.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(common_dir = list(intersect(dir_list, dir_list2)))

data
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). I have created below dummy data for testing purpose.

```
data <- structure(list(a = 1:3, dir_list = list(list(2, 3, 4), list(1, 
    2, 3), list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), dir_list2 = list(list(3, 
    4), list(2, 3), list(9))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```